# Show that $\iint_{X \times Y}\varphi(x)k(x,y)\psi(y) d(\mu \times \nu)=\int_Y \Big[\int_X\varphi(x)k(x,y)d\mu \Big] \psi(y) d\nu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $k(x,y)$ be a bounded Borel measurable function on $X \times Y$ and let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be Radon measure on $X$ and $Y$

i. Show that $\iint_{X \times Y}\varphi(x)k(x,y)\psi(y) d(\mu \times \nu)=\int_Y \Big[\int_X\varphi(x)k(x,y)d\mu \Big] \psi(y) d\nu
=\int_X\varphi(x) \Big[\int_Y k(x,y)\psi(y) d\nu \Big]d \mu$

for all $\varphi \in C_c(X)$ and $\psi \in C_c(Y).$

ii. Show that $k=0(\mu \times \nu)$- a.e. if the above integral vanishes for all $\varphi \in C_c(X),\psi \in C_c(Y)$

**Attempt:** I thought about using Fubini's Theorem, but one of the Fubini's condition is $\nu$ has to be complete, Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: There is a version of Fubini-Tonelli's theorem which involves the completion of the product measure, but the [basic formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem) of the theorem just assumes $\mu$ and $\nu$ to be $\sigma$-finite (which they may be taken to be because they are Radon and $\varphi$ and $\psi$ have compact support).

Comment: I might have been too hasty: while wikipedia actually says what it says, for some reason Royden's *Real Analysis* has completeness of $\mu$ and $\nu$ in its hypothesis.

Comment: ... but it says in the comments to the theorem that it is not crucial. OK.

Comment: correct, Royden has $\nu$ complete in its hypothesis